# Having trouble using composite key with SQLite in SQLAlchemy, keep getting errors about passing too many parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on building an API for the backend of a mobile app and got in a little over my head. The database stores user info for the app users. I'm completely new to python and databases, so the debugging has been a little rough but I finally got it working using user email as the primary key. Unfortunately I then found out I needed to add an int as a primary key as well to differentiate between two different user types.

Now I have no idea how to deal with the composite primary key. I set it up in the database and updated the rest of the code for it but when I use the SQLAlchemy function `User.query.get()` it tells me that I'm giving it 3 arguments instead of 2:

```
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Class stuff:

```
class User(db.Model):
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    tutor = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120))
    location = db.Column(db.String(120))
    s_courses = db.Column(db.Text)
    t_courses = db.Column(db.Text)
    available = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    in_session = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    status = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    stars = db.Column(db.Float)
    rate = db.Column(db.Float)
    duration = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, location, s_courses, t_courses, available, in_session,
                 status, stars, rate, duration, tutor):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.location = location
        self.s_courses = s_courses
        self.t_courses = t_courses
        self.available = available
        self.in_session = in_session
        self.status = status
        self.stars = stars
        self.rate = rate
        self.duration = duration
        self.tutor = tutor

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 's_courses', 't_courses', 'available', 'in_session',
                  'status', 'stars', 'rate', 'duration', 'tutor')


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
```

Get user method:

```
@app.route("/user/<key1>/<key2>", methods=["GET"])
def user_detail(key1, key2):
    user = User.query.get(key1, key2)
    if user is not None:
            return user_schema.jsonify(user)
    return jsonify("User not found")
```

From what I've seen this usually just means that the self parameter needs to be added, but as far as I can tell this method is outside of any class and self doesn't seem to link to anything.

Comment: Query object's `get()` method takes the primary key as a parameter. But you are passing two arguments `key1` and `key2`.

Comment: While the problem itself is simple: in case of a composite key you pass `Query.get()` a tuple of key values as the sole argument, "Unfortunately I then found out I needed to add an int as a primary key as well to differentiate between two different user types" seems like an XY problem. Why do you think that you need an int as a primary key as well?